# How to find the averages of an argument which consists of nested arrays in python

Tags: python

This is the argument i would be passing to my logic.

```
var= '--a1=[[1,2,3],[]] --a2=4'
```

I need to find the average of these two arrays as mentioned below.

```
"1 4"
```

because [1,2,3] evaluates to 2, [] evaluates to 0 and the average of [2,0] is 1.

I have tried the code as given below,but its of no use.

```
var="--a1=[1,2,3] --a2=4.0"
args=var.split(' ')
args=[s[s.find('=') + 1:] for s in args]
print (args)
for elem in args:
    for i in elem:
        print (i)
```

Can someone please help me

Comment: a2 isn’t an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

(assuming you want the *average*, not the item located at the middle. If the middle is what you need, you should be able to adapt the following solution by yourself)

```py
var="--a1=[1,2,3] --a2=4.0"
args=var.split(' ')
args=[s[s.find('=') + 1:] for s in args]

for elem in args:
  # remove everything but numbers and commas (we don't care about nested arrays here)
  # "[[[1,2,3],[]]" --> "1,2,3,"
  stripped = "".join([ c for c in elem if c.isdigit() or c == ','])
  # now, split by commas, and convert each number from string to int (ignore empty strings with `if d`)
  # "1,2,3," --> [1,2,3]
  numbers = [int(d) for d in stripped.split(",") if d]
  # now, just compute the mean and print
  avg = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
  print(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've utilized the inbuilt eval() function to solve your problem. I've tried my best to explain the code in the comments. Take a look at the code below:

```
def average(array): # returns the average of the values in an array
    n = 0
    if array == []:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in array:
            n += i
        return n/len(array)

var= '--a1=[[1,2,3],[]] --a2=4'

start = var.find('[') # I used this method the find the first "[" in the string
end = len(var) - var[::-1].find(']') # I reversed the string to find the last "]" in the string

a1 = eval(var[start:end]) # converts the list in the form of string to a list
# for example "[1,2,3]" will be converted into [1,2,3] using the eval function

if var.count('[') == 1: # the code below requires a 2d array so this part converts the array to 2d if 1d is passed
    a1 = [a1]
averages = [] # to store the averages of all of the lists
for array in a1:
    averages.append(average(array)) # finding average for each array in the string

print(averages)
```

Comment: its giving me output as 1.0 instead of [2,0]

Comment: I assumed you wanted the overall average of all of the array like you mentioned in the explanation. It returns the value you want now.